# Upgraded internet package, slower downloads?

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, home-networking

I've just upgraded to a new internet package with my ISP which boasts 50 Mb/s download and 30 Mb/s upload, much faster than my previous 6 Mb/s download and 1 Mb/s upload. However, my desktop computer on a wireless connection is experiencing incredibly slow download speeds, maxing around 400 kb/s (in µTorrent, Steam etc). Browsing is also a real pain - I can't even try using Firefox because it always hangs and takes forever to load (if it loads at all), while my MacBook Pro is gaining full advantage and downloading and surfing the web at super fast speeds.

I've already had a guy come in and change the router, but nothing changed. I'm constantly scanning my computer for viruses and spyware, but it hasn't found anything. The really weird thing is that when I go to a connection speed test site, I get pretty much what I should be getting.

What could be causing the downloads and browsing to be so slow?

Comment: Hmm. I'm sure the SU networking experts will give you a better answer, but have you checked the DNS settings on the slow computer?

Comment: Hi Skyler, welcome to Super User! You did a good job explaining what happened, but in order to help you further, you might want to [edit] your question and give us a few more details, like what hardware you're using: PCs? Which Mac exactly? Operating systems and their versions involved, the router model before and after the switch, etc.

Comment: You said that you use wireless, that's correct? Which wireless adapter in your computer? Do you know if it is a 802.11a ,802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n ?

Comment: have you run any malware/virus scans on the pc too see if it is infected? have you tried changeding your wireless channels to see if that is any better?

Answer (score 0):

i thought this problem related with temp. filles.jus go through below path and delete all files from there.
•%systemdrive%\Windows\Temp
generally due to this internet goes down.